# Plantilla de blade en auth no carga estilo

Tags: php, laravel, artisan, laragon

estoy empezando en **laravel** y pues ya voy por la parte de Authentication (**auth**) tengo entendido que en la version de **laravel 7** ya no se puede usar el comando **make:auth** que hoy en esta version es **ui:auth**

Lo primero que hago creo mi proyecto

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel [nombre_proyecto]
```

Lo siguiente que hago es en el archivo .env declaro las variable del nombre de la base de datos antes de hacer la migracion

```
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=root
```

Lo tercero es crear la base de datos desde la consola para luego poder hacer la migracion

```
php artisan migrate
```

ya teniendo listo la migracion ejecuto los comando ui:auth, que en la documentacion esta asi

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Seguido

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

tambien ejecuto los comando

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intentaste utilizar `php artisan serve`? Revisa el código fuente en el navegador para ver hacia a donde apuntan los archivos css y js

Comment: @JonathanOrta fijece que no, por que estoy usando laragon y ya me crea los host virtuales, pero si he pensando intentar asi de esa forma.

Comment: @JonathanOrta si yo le doy inspeccionar me dice Ha fallado la carga del <script> con origen "http://blog.test/js/app.js". que esta en la ruta resoucer/js/app.js

Comment: Qué tienes en tu Laravel mix? Y, sí estás incluyendo el scaffolding del paquete ui en tu entrypoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que no solo son copiar comandos, con la nueva `UI` tienes que compilar el código resultante. repasando.

```
1. composer require laravel/ui
2. php artisan ui vue --auth // puede ser vue | react | bootstrap
3. npm install
4. npm run dev // Aquí está el problema
```

si vas a trabajar con `vue JS` o `React JS`, Ejecutas

```
npm run watch
```

pero si solo usarás `Bootstrap`

```
npm run production
```

Aunque no es necesario, ya que en  el archivo `app.blade.php` cambias los `script por CDN`

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

los CDN de Bootstrap, jquery.js, popper.js, bootstrap.js

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">

CDN de Bootstrap.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahí te falta importar el estilo , o sea bootstrap:

El comando que tienes que utilizar es

> php artisan ui bootstrap

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en mi caso yo solo copie los CDN de bootstrap en el archivo app.blade.php y listo, no fue necesario agregar ningún otro comando.