# Fallo en la vista del login con Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Mi versión de Laravel es la 7.18.0

Mediante estas instrucciones en la consola:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Tengo disponibles los controladores, vistas, etc, para realizar la autenticación en Laravel

Pero cuando cargo la vista principal no se ve correctamente, así es cómo se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué ocurre, por qué no se ve bien mi vista?

Gracias!

Comment: Te falta el estilo prueba poniendo este comando "php artisan ui bootstrap"

Comment: Buenas... Después de poner ese comando me dice "Bootstrap scaffolding installed successfully". Pero también me dice "Please run npm install && npm run dev to compile your fresh scaffolding". Pero cuando pongo npm install me dice "-bash: npm: no se encontró la orden"

Comment: Aqui esta respondido justamente esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369257/plantilla-de-blade-en-auth-no-carga-estilo/369343#369343 , espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: ¿Verificaste si tú plantilla blade tiene los inlude correctos de la sección donde van los archivos de estilo css?, puedes checarlo en la carpeta resources/Views/layouts

Comment: Buenas, en el archivo "app.blade.php" que está en el directorio resources/views/layouts veo esta línea: <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> y si hago una búsqueda en el directorio de la aplicación del archivo app.css no aparece por ningún lado, no se si será ese el problema...

Comment: Te falta instalar npm, por eso te mara el error `"-bash: npm: no se encontró la orden"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que verificar que estés cargando correctamente las hojas de estilos.
Has compilado los assets?

```
npm install
npm run watch (si quieres recompilar automáticamente al hacer los cambios en el frontend)
```

Si en cambio no quieres usar laravel mix ni compilar los assets, intenta esto para que comprendas el problema. Solo con incluir el cdn de bootstrap, verás corregidos los estilos

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <!-- CSRF Token -->
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

   <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

   <!-- Scripts -->
   <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

   <!-- Styles -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Puedes crear tú mismo el fichero app.css en public/css para tus estilos personalizados.

Comment: Buenas, qué son los assets y para qué hay que compilarlos?. Cuando pongo npm install me dice "-bash: npm: no se encontró la orden"

Comment: Hola. Entiendo que hayas hecho una instalación fresca de Laravel. Luego de esto que has hecho, necesitas que se carguen los estilos, en este caso Bootstrap. Ya sea usando laravel mix o intentando linkearlo directame

Comment: Juanqui tienes que instalar npm, te dice npm not found porque no lo tienes instalado

Comment: Para un desarrollo más solido del proyecto, será mejor que si todo esto te suena raro, que cargues los estilos sin compilar ni usar webpack. Si es por estudiar, ve a la pagina de npm e instalalo globalmente para que lo tengas en futuros proyectos. Buena suerte artesano!

Comment: @Juaqui he editado un poco mi respuesta para er si te ayuda más. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Esternome. He probado añadiendo la línea del cdn de bootstrap a mi fichero app.blade.php y ya me ha cargado los estilos correctamente. También he instalado npm y ya he podido ejecutar los comandos npm install y npm run dev, entiendo que con eso he compilado los assets?. Estoy empezando con laravel y estoy muy verde aún. Lo que he comprobado es que la carpeta del proyecto ha pasado de ocupar 36MB a 139MB, tengo que ejecutar de nuevo estos comandos cada vez que quiera usar el login de laravel en un proyecto nuevo? Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Hola @Juaqui. La subida de MB se debe a la instalación de módulos a partir de tu npm install (están en node_modules). Revisa como funciona Laravel Mix y webpack si quieres trabajar de ese modo. Si hubieses instalado primero npm y compilado, no hubiese sido necesario el cdn de bootstrap porque al compilar lo instala y lo agrega por ti. Revisa bien cada cosa para que tomes el camino correcto y no termines duplicando tus dependencias. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo error. Lo que pasa es que se tiene un **npm** desactualizado.

Lo que realicé es solo ingresar de manera separada el **front** que es el código:

- `composer require laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss --dev`
- `php artisan ui tailwindcss --auth`
- `php artisan ui react`
- `npm install && npm run dev`
- `npm remove laravel-mix`
- `npm install laravel-mix --save-dev`
- `npm install cross-env --save-dev`
- `npm install && npm run dev`

Después de esto te saldrá el cuadro de instalación completada de js y css
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]